# FQL Unable to get zip code of friend

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using FQL to  fetch friend's location using the field current_location . I can view fields like city,state but the zip code always returns as null. I suspect something to do with the permissions. Cant we view the friend's zip code? Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because location is just a city/town name, it is not a fully qualified address with street address and zip code.  Let's take a place like Los Angeles, CA which has numerous Zip Codes.  How can Facebook know which of the myriad of Zip codes the user is in, without revealing the hidden street address information which is purposely excluded from the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry that I had to repost. I was unsure whether I posted in the right forum as I am new